# Rails open-uri breaking on path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, open-uri

I'm trying to get a url using open-uri.

my code is outrageously simple

```
   url = open("http://localhost:3000/descriptions")

   return render :text => url.to_json
```

When I run this code, I get a timeout error.

When I request just "http://localhost:3000", I get my home page (which is correct). 
So it seems this is breaking on the path somewhere. 
I've tried using net-http with uri (not sure if that would make a difference) and I still have the same issue. I want to get a path and a query, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: Break up the URL into domain/path and open() that -  the Net::HTTP documentation in Ruby describes this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course: I guess you're using the default webrick server which is only able to handle one request at a time:

- one is consumed by your controller's action
- one is consumed by your `open` call

Two solutions:

- replace webrick in dev with thin or unicorn or whatever
- launch two servers with webrick: `rails s` & `rails s -p 3001`. One on port 3000, another on port 3001

Comment: That was exactly it. I didn't realize webrick only allowed one request at a time. Strange that it would retrieve the homepage and only break on the path though. Good to know that is the reason.